# Typescript/React/MaterialUI/JSS project: override CSS for a single React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, jss

I am trying to understand how to override the CSS/formatting/theme for just a single React component in a Typescript/React/MaterialUI/JSS project.  Below is the code, however the {classes.gridStyle} within the JSX doesn't get processed (see screenshot below the code snippet). I can see it show up in the browser debugger as unmodified and the typescript editor is also giving me a warning that variable "classes" is never used.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Grid, createStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles(() =>
  createStyles({
    gridStyle: {
      display: 'inline-block',
      padding: '0 20px',
      height: '40px',
    },
    '& div': {
      display: 'inline-block',
      fontSize: '10px',
      padding: '0 20px',
      height: '40px',
    },
  })
);

export default function HomeHeader(): JSX.Element {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Grid item className="{classes.gridStyle}">
      Row 1 completely override css experiment...
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

[Issue inside browser debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQQ0D.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
className="{classes.gridStyle}">
```

should be

```
className={classes.gridStyle}>
```